How to sort the SOCRATA DISCOVERY API results?
From https://dev.socrata.com/docs/other/discovery#?route=overview
It appears that the SOCRATA catalog search API can sort the results.
THIS IS NOT THE DATA API, IT IS THE CATALOG discovery API and $order does not seem to work in the CATALOG search.
Can someone show an example?
We'd like to sort on updatedAt
Here's an example that does not work:
https://api.us.socrata.com/api/catalog/v1?q=demographic%20NYC%20school&limit=100&$order=updatedAt%20desc
But without sorting it does work:
https://api.us.socrata.com/api/catalog/v1?q=demographic%20NYC%20school&limit=100&tags=
From the documentation:
Additional API facts
Search without any parameters returns the set of data you are authorized to see. 
Any parameter usage serves to filter (or **sort**) this set of data - i.e. no parameters 
allow you to see more data than a search without parameters. This is important 
to know when considering parameters that let you search for assets not found 
in the public catalog. If you are unauthorized to see such things, your 
results will be empty.


You can't use SoQL Clauses ($where, $order, etc ..) on Socrata's Discovery API - so drop the $ and the error goes away. Read more about it here
Sort url:
https://api.us.socrata.com/api/catalog/v1?order=updatedAt
Using your url:
https://api.us.socrata.com/api/catalog/v1?q=demographic%20NYC%20school&limit=100&tags=&order=updatedAt
What I would use:
https://api.us.socrata.com/api/catalog/v1?only=dataset&limit=1000&order=updatedAt&domains=data.cityofnewyork.us&q=demographic%20school
